# How to pass multiple files to a Bash script as variables?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script, let's call it `myscript`, that is supposed to accept files in the current working directory as variables and perform various actions on them.

I've been able to set up this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

command1 $file
command2 $file
```

that works fine, when I run `myscript myfile1.ext` it correctly executes `command1 myfile1.ext` and `command2 myfile1.ext`.

The problem is that I'd like to pass more filenames on the same instance, to speed up things, and be able to do this: `myscript myfile1.ext myfile2.ext myfile3.ext myfile4.ext` and have each one of these files be processed by the script. Right now, even if I pass more filenames, only the first one is processed.

How should I modify this script to sequentially work on multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward approach is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in "$@"; do
   command1 "$file"
   command2 "$file"
done
```

Notes:

- The code is not Bash-specific, it works in `sh` (hence my shebang).
- [Quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/108618) like I did.

You can implement more complex logic with `shift` shell builtin. See [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_26) or `help shift` in Bash.